# WordPress Lazyloading images breaking Fancybox

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fancybox, lazy-loading

I am using WordPress. Fancy box and a lazy loader plugin. However, since adding the lazy load plugin the fancy box has stopped working.

When you initiate the fancybox plugin, you do so with some javascript like so:

```
var select = $('a[href$=".bmp"],a[href$=".gif"],a[href$=".jpg"],a[href$=".jpeg"],a[href$=".png"],a[href$=".BMP"],a[href$=".GIF"],a[href$=".JPG"],a[href$=".JPEG"],a[href$=".PNG"]');

select.attr('rel', 'fancybox');
select.fancybox();
```

This fires with the rest of the javascript when the document has loaded.
However, now I am getting this error:

> select.fancybox is not a function

I am assuming that the lazy loading plugin is taking the images out of the equation so this function isnt able to do anything.

I have tried attaching it again afterwards but I feel like I am going in the wrong direction:

```
$('html').on('mousemove', 'a[href$=".bmp"],a[href$=".gif"],a[href$=".jpg"],a[href$=".jpeg"],a[href$=".png"],a[href$=".BMP"],a[href$=".GIF"],a[href$=".JPG"],a[href$=".JPEG"],a[href$=".PNG"]', function(){

            $(this).attr('rel', 'fancybox');
            $(this).fancybox();
            
        });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress now includes browser-level lazy-loading attribute for all images, using the 'loading' image attribute (`loading="lazy"`). Perhaps you no longer need the lazy loading plugin?

See here:
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/01/29/lazy-loading-images-in-wordpress-core/

Comment: Fancybox isnt a lazy loader. And the issue is because the lazy loader is dynamically adding the images after. I might not need the lazy loader but the issue is still there when turned off.

Comment: I would look here: [Fancybox is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992054/fancybox-is-not-a-function)